# jQuery simultaneously slide text to center from left / slide text from center to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sliding

I want to be able to have the "hello" slide from the center to the right out of frame (and fade out) while at the same time have the "there" slide from the left to the center (and fade in) when the button is clicked. But I can't figure out how to  achieve this without having the divs on separate lines.

Ultimately I want to build a sliding menu that is controllable with "next" and "prev" buttons, so I figured I'd start with something small. Thank you!

HTML:

```
  <div id="test">
    hello
  </div>

  <div id="test2">
    there
  </div>

  <button id="next">
    Next
  </button>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#next").click(function() {

     $("#test").hide("slide", {
       direction: "right"
     }, 1000);

     $("#test2").show("slide", {
       direction: "left"
     }, 1000);

   });

 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qftqzr6f/

Comment: what do you mean by "without having the divs on separate lines" ?

Comment: @DinoMyte I think that he doesn't want to have two different divs, but why 
pozufu?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it without [defining a set height](https://jsfiddle.net/qftqzr6f/2/). Do you have that restriction?

Comment: @DinoMyte Right now when the button is clicked the user can see the first div disappear when the next button shifts up, then shifts back down when the second div appears.

Comment: @Stryner That's actually exactly what I was looking for! So how does putting the divs in a container make them inline like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position absolute these divs. See modified example.

```
#wrapper{height:50px;position:relative}
#wrapper div{position:absolute;width:100%}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghL19cge/